# Как сделать счетчик посещений на js/php/mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Всем привет, я бекенд разработчик, учу js и хочу реализовать такую вот функцию:

Счетчик посещений на сайте через js+php+mysql

Вот только с javascript еще туго и примерно вижу это вот так:

Мы подключаем на странице сайта наш счетчик примерно так `<script src="http://site.com/count.js"></script>`

И теперь при каждом обновлении данной страницы через js код который мы подключили будут отправляться данные о просмотре в обработчик который будет находится по ссылке http://site.com/co.php

Буду благодарен за js код который будет передавать информацию о обновлении, серверную часть возьму на себя

Comment: Обычно тут помогают решать проблемы, а не делают работу за других.
Гугл уже перестал работать? Там масса материалов по теме.

И да, большое спасибо, что берете на себя серверную часть. Это самая трудная часть работы, несомненно.

Comment: Не надо делать самому счётчик посещений. Идея крайне неудачная. Берите готовый.

Comment: Счётчик посещений != счётчик перезагрузок страниц...

Answer (score 0):

Если пользоваться чистым Javascript, то примерно так:

```
// Функция, которая отправляет GET запрос
function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
// Вызываем функцию
httpGet("http://site.com/co.php");
```

Данные можно передавать как параметры в url